# JMP cannot read SAS outout file from R

Tags: r, file, sas, output, sas-jmp

This is a troubleshooting question.

This might seem weird but I was told I had to take a data set from R and output it into a SAS file in order for someone else to work with it.

I used `write_sas(faithful, "faithful.sas7bdat")` which utilizes the `library(haven)`

It seems to work: writes the file, does not produce any errors, seems to be an appropriate size for what I expect, however, when I try to read the file into JMP, I get this error "Cannot import Table. BASE driver, Table does not exist or cannot be accessed or created".

I know this is not an issue with JMP because I have opened other SAS files with no issues from the same file as my output.

I am thinking it could be an issue with the way R writes the metadata for the SAS file. I am looking for any insight or theories on how to troubleshoot this issue.

**Update:**

Apparently this is a common issue, from reading this thread it makes it sound like there is a current bug preventing it from working.

https://github.com/tidyverse/haven/issues/224

Has anyone actually had `write_sas` work though?

Comment: Did you really create a SAS dataset with mixed case in the physical filename?  That does not work for SAS on Unix and perhaps it will also not work with JMP.  Try making sure the filename is in all lowercase letters.

Comment: I did try all lower case for the file name as well, did not solve the problem but thank you anyway for the tip.

Comment: Did you try writing a SAS export file instead? Can JMP read that format?